# What is the major difference in MSECE vs MSEECS and how should I pick?

Tags: graduate-admissions, united-states, computer-science, electrical-engineering, machine-learning

I am a Fall'22 aspirant and looking for universities in the US. I have completed my undergraduate studies in Electronics and Communications Engineering. I want to pursue my master's degree in the domain that will be a blend of hardware and software for Machine Learning or edge computing as a whole. I am currently employed at SiFive and working on a project that is actually based on "AI on the edge". So, my work experience is relevant and projects too, what degree should I be going for MSECE or MSEECS? My main interest lies in modelling and also compilers for deep/machine learning. How do I compare and shortlist the universities based on the above filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The terms "MSECE" and "MSEECS" aren't standardized (or even especially common) in the US. You need to look at the details of any given program on their web-site. These things are set at the state (of which we have 50) and even the university level. Many programs will have a list of required and optional courses on their site.

For some, the list of faculty will also include which courses they teach.

If you find a program that seems interesting, you can communicate with the graduate program director (probably a faculty member) to see if it meets your goals.

---

Note however, that, in general, Computer Science tends to be more software based and Electrical Engineering tends toward hardware. Not a clean split, however.